# Sharepoint/AD authentication

Tags: java, sharepoint, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have a web application that makes use of spring security and authenticates users against an AD server using LDAP so we do not store the users password in our application. This all works fine.

Now my application is trying to make RESTful webservice calls to a sharepoint server which requires NTML authentication. The sharepoint server also authenticates users by doing an LDAP lookup to the same AD server.

Is there a way to avoid having to ask the user for their credentials again (somehow letting sharepoint know that the user has been authenticated with the use of a token or something?)